# Define birthday query handler in SOLR

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a date field and I want to query to get all the events that their years are different from today.

So, I've create another field in schema.xml:

```
<field name="myDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="myDateString" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

<copyField source="myDate" dest="myDateString"/>
```

Then I've defined a handler in SolrConfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/onthisday" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">15</int>
      <str name="df">myDateString</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="q">*-08-10T*</str>
      <str name="fl">*</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Using this handler, I can find all events in October 8:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/article/onthisday?q=*-10-07T*
```

But, I want to use default today values in the solrconfig.xml file. I've tested this (which does not work):

```
<str name="q">*-/MONTH-/DAYT*</str>
```

How can I set the default query value using current date for string field?

Answer (score 0):

The search keyword you are searching for is Date Math. You can find a couple of examples in the [Solr reference guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser).

Your specific query might be something like:

```
birthdate:[* TO NOW/YEAR-1YEAR]
```

Comment: It returns all the documents before the last year, assume today is 2013-10-10, I need 2012-10-10, 2011-10-10, 2010-10-10,....